# list_entry return value

Tags: linux, list, linux-kernel, kernel, return-value

Hay guys!

I'm changing the kernel code at the Rat Hat OS and I want to use the macro "list entry".
I can't find anywhere what is the return value in case of failure..

What will it return if the list is empty? or at any other case...

Thanks!!
Ami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this list_head in two ways

1) independent single global variable, to HOLD the list as head to all

we can not use the **list_entry** on this variable event though there are list members 
in it. because this is not part of any structure.

2) we can use list_head as member of the your structure, wile adding to the list you will 
   give this member pointer to the list HEAD.

we will use **list_entry** on this member to get the your structure even though your 
   list member is not part of any List(it initialized with next=NULL and priv=NULL)
   you can get structure there is no way to fail.

list_entry is simple container_of() we use this to get the structure pointer using member pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something undefined if the list is empty.  (You're trying to dereference a list pointer that's not in a struct of the list's element type)

Generally, if you must use list_entry directly, you want to check if list_empty first.  This will verify your list head doesn't point to itself.

Otherwise stick to always using the list_for_each macros which will generate a for loop over your elements.